# Deployment of QT apps on linux

Tags: qt, ubuntu-14.04

I have developed Qt app in ubuntu-14.04 operating system . I need to deploy the executable  file into target system without using any tool.
 Can u please guide me how I should proceed .Any information about it would be useful for me . Waiting for your reply.. Thanks in advance..

Thanks and Regards,
Aryan

Comment: did you look here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html? what is not working for you?

Comment: what do you mean by "without using any tool"??

Comment: deploying exe file in other system with required libraries and plugins

Comment: when i run the executable file i get syntax error  as word unexpected (expecting ")")..

Comment: Are you saying that the target system is not Ubuntu?  In which case, you'll need to learn the appropriate package manager for the target.  If we don't know what the target is, then you can't expect specific answers.

Comment: target system is ubuntu 10,04 only

Comment: i shoould not install Qt craeter in target environment ..without that i need to run it

Answer (score 2):

**Deploying a dynamically linked Qt application :**

You should place Qt `.so` files along the release version of your executable. These are `libQtCore.so`, `libQtGui.so` and possibly the ones for other modules that you have used. These `so` files are in your installed Qt directory in lib folder or in the directory `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`. If you are using plugins you should place their so files in a folder named `plugins` beside your binary. In case of using icons and images you should ship their so files like `libqico.so` and `libqsvg.so` in a folder named `imageformats`.

**Gathering required shared libraries :**

If you want your application to run independently on a bare installed Linux, you should gather all dependent shared libraries and put them in your application directory. You can simply do it by a shell script named [cpld](http://h3manth.com/content/copying-shared-library-dependencies). You can easily copy all dependencies to a folder.

It's worthy to note that you can put this in your .pro file to cause the dynamic linker to look in the same directory as your Qt application at runtime in Linux :

```
unix:{
    # suppress the default RPATH if you wish
    QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH=
    # add your own with quoting gyrations to make sure $ORIGIN gets to the command line unexpanded
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += "-Wl,-rpath,\'\$$ORIGIN\'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to deploy the executable file into target system without using
>   any tool.

That's unlikely.  I expect you actually need to package your application so that it can be installed using the standard package-management system (i.e. `dpkg`, `apt-get` and friends).

Read up on creating Debian packages and come back here (or, more likely, the Linux&Unix stackexchange) when you've made an effort.

Comment: deploying exe file in other system with required libraries and plugins