# Qt 5.8 (ubuntu 16.04) application deployment on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu

I have an application created by using Qt 5.8. The app is developed on Ubuntu 16.04.

After run `ldd app_name` I can see the libraries the app is using:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe16bef000)
libmysqlclient.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.20 (0x00007f1f455b0000)
libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /home/r0ng/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f1f44d7f000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /home/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f1f445e3000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f1f43ec3000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1f43b41000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1f4392a000)
... ...
```

Now, I am trying to deployment my application on other Linux machines.
The first thing I checked is the official doc：
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html

I found I do NOT have the configure script.

```
find -type f -name "configure*"
./Docs/Qt-5.8/qtgamepad/images/configuregamepadbuttons-example.png
./Docs/Qt-5.8/qtdoc/configure-options.html
./Examples/Qt-5.8/gamepad/configureButtons/configureButtons.pro
./Examples/Qt-5.8/gamepad/configureButtons/doc/images/configuregamepadbuttons-example.png
./5.8/gcc_64/mkspecs/features/configure_base.prf
./5.8/gcc_64/mkspecs/features/configure.prf
./5.8/android_armv7/mkspecs/features/configure_base.prf
./5.8/android_armv7/mkspecs/features/configure.prf
```

Do I need to install Qt in a specific way to get the configure script? I also try to find the script in Qt Maintenace tool. But nothing there.

Another attempt is based on this thread
[Deployment of QT apps on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506314/deployment-of-qt-apps-on-linux). It seems Qt project file (*.pro) allowing developers copy all dynamic libraries to the application's current working directory. But I have no clue to set value ORIGIN. And what does -Wl -rpath do in that case?

Anyone knows how to let the Qt load *.so file from the current working directory?

Thanks

Comment: "Do I need to install Qt in a specific way to get the configure script?" I would assume that you need to build and install Qt from source -- rather than install a pre-built binary package -- to have a `configure` script. That's the convention for *nix software.

Comment: You can take a look to [Deployment with package](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/debian/9925/create-a-debian-package#t=201705290824497346076)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `configure` script is present when you build Qt from sources and probably you don't need that. To load shared libraries from the current working directory you need to point the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable to the directory where the shared libraries are located. You can find an example of a script that does this in the official Qt documentation for [Linux Deployment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html). For example i use this modified script on my deployments:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
dirname=`dirname $0`
tmp="${dirname#?}"

if [ "${dirname%$tmp}" != "/" ]; then
dirname=$PWD/$dirname
fi
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$dirname
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$dirname/myapp "$@"
```

And this is an example of the directory layout of one of my Qt apps that i currently distribute:

```
./myapp
./myapp.png
./myapp.sh
./libQt5X11Extras.so.5
./libQt5Core.so.5
./libQt5Network.so.5
./libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
./libicui18n.so.56
./libQt5Gui.so.5
./libicuuc.so.56
./libicudata.so.56
./sqldrivers
./sqldrivers/libqsqlite.so
./libQt5Widgets.so.5
./translations
./translations/qt_es.qm
./translations/qt_en.qm
./platforms
./platforms/libqxcb.so
./libQt5Sql.so.5
./libQt5DBus.so.5
./bearer
./bearer/libqnmbearer.so
./bearer/libqgenericbearer.so
./bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so
./imageformats
./imageformats/libqjpeg.so
```

Of course, you will need more or less libraries depending of the dependencies of your application. I currently use the official Qt 5.8 installer so the shared libraries comes from there instead of the ones provided by the distro.